# display data in birt report

Tags: sql, birt, maximo

Dear stackOverflow community,

I am new to birt and sql, kindly be with me if its a very basic question for u.

I have two tables in DB

1.COMPANY- companyid, name, phone, address, and other info

2.COMPANY_OWNER-  company id, ownername , percentage share

my requirement is as below

display a simple table report ,one row per company and in that row one cell contains all (owners - % )for a company.

PFA for more clarification

[image: report sample]
note: Number of owners can vary

Comment: Did you have a question? I think you should read [ask] and [example]. Beyond that, please tell us if you are using normal BIRT or "Maximo"-BIRT, as the latter is a bit more restrictive.